# Read GPS incoming data in python

Tags: python, sockets, gps

I'm developing a python script that reads a port and print an answer. The idea is to get data from a gps.

This is the code I'm using.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
host = ''       # your IP address
port = 5000    # pick a port you want to listen on. 
backlog = 5     # number of clients you could handle at once
size = 1024     # max size of data packet

# create socket:
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# connect to host / port:
s.bind((host,port))
# start listening:
s.listen(backlog)
print "listening on: " + str(port)
# stay in this loop until ctrl-c is typed at console:
while 1:
    client, address = s.accept()
    data = client.recv(size)
    if data:
        print data          # echo data to console
        client.send(data)   # echo data to client (may confuse your application, great for browser)
    client.close()
```

Now I can connect via telnet and send a message, I'll get the output in the server. Also I can connect via http: // [ip] : [port] and get the output. But I cannot get any information from the GPS, although it is online, and I've re checked the configuration. I've also tried with other devices. No luck.

My question is: Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't understand what *"get any information from the GPS"* means. can you please elaborate what your GPS actually is and how is it supposed to communicate with a network application?

Comment: I try to get coordinates from a GPS via GPRS. The GPS connects via GPRS to port 5000 and send data. I'm not sure about the format of the data, just want to see it.

Comment: sure it's TCP? sure the GPS device is in the same network? there are lots of open questions since we don't know what GPS you're working with and how it is connected. maybe there's some handshake procedure necessary?

Comment: It's TCP, but at least I should see something in the output right?

Answer (score 0):

Threading needs to be imported.

You need `s.` to write the data and `def` to run the script.

The code should be like this:

```
from threading import *
class client(thread):
  def __init__(self, socket, address):
      Thread.__init__(self)
      s.sock = socket
      s.addr = address
  s.start()
def run(self)
    while 1:
    data = s.client.recv(size)
    print ('send data:' data)
    self.sock.send(b'Sending')

serversocket.listen(5)
print ('server start listing')
while 1:
     clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept()
     client(clientsocket, address)
```

Comment: Please don't encourage `import *`